# What is the pka of dibromoacetic acid?

Tags: aqueous-solution

There is a reference of 1.48 value at room temperature which is a different value from an experimental study.

Comment: Could you tell us what reference this is? and what experimental study?

Comment: That's a reasonable value for water pKa of such acid. BTW if the difference you found isn't more then 0.1-0.2 it's not like either of them is necessarily "wrong".

Comment: An IUPAC reference of ionization constants. An experimental study that shows the breakdown pathway of another chemical.

Comment: It's very different than the reference.